# Is it possible to set a RingCentral user's timezone through the API?

Tags: ringcentral, settings

I was looking thru the API for how to set timezone and cannot find it. Is there not a way to set the timezone thru the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user's timezone is set as part of their extension properties and is read using the Extension Info API and set via the Update Extension Info endpoint, not a specific timezone endpoint. I'll start with the read because the response provides an easy way to create the update timezone request.

**Read Timezone**

To read the user's current timezone, retrieve the user's settings info using the following endpoint. You will get a lot of properties. From the response, you can see how to create the update request.

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}
```

The response will contain a lot of information including the timezone as shown. Use this JSON path in your update request with a timezone id shown later below.

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222",
    "id": 22222222,
    "extensionNumber": "101",
    ...
    "regionalSettings": {
        "timezone": {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone/60",
            "id": "60",
            "name": "Pacific/Honolulu",
            "description": "Hawaii",
            "bias": "-600"
        },...
    }
}
```

See more in the API Reference:

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#User-Settings-loadExtensionInfo

**Set Timezone**

To set a user's timezone, update the user's extension endpoint using the `PUT` method and specify the timezone id in the body as shown. The timezone ids can be found in the timezone endpoint shown next.

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}

{
    "regionalSettings": {
        "timezone": {
            "id": "58"
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#User-Settings-updateExtension

**List Timezones**

To get a list of timezones, call the timezone endpoint:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone
```

The response provides a list of timezones with description and a timezone id that is used in the update user settings request.

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone?page=1&perPage=100",
    "records": [
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone/1",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "GMT",
            "description": "Casablanca, Monrovia, Reykjavik",
            "bias": "0"
        },
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone/2",
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Europe/Lisbon",
            "description": "Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London",
            "bias": "0"
        },
        ...
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone/91",
            "id": "91",
            "name": "Asia/Pyongyang",
            "description": "Pyongyang",
            "bias": "510"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {...},
    "navigation": {...}
}
```

See the API Reference for more information:

https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Regional-Settings-listTimezones