# Time zone supporting RingCentral API

Tags: ringcentral

I was checking this article where user time zone can be set and changed in going into configuration ***Settings > User Details > Settings and Permissions***  under ***Regional Settings***
reference:

https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/10602-user-set-hours-operation-time-zone?language=en_US

What if I want to set time zone with RingCentral API which all API support modifying time zone? Can it be done with any RingCentral API?

I haven't seen anything similar can be done with API.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set a RingCentral user's timezone through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681789/is-it-possible-to-set-a-ringcentral-users-timezone-through-the-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***Update Extension Info*** endpoint API using the **PUT** method and specify the timezone id

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}
{
    "regionalSettings": {
        "timezone": {
            "id": "58"
        }
    }
}
```

ref: [Is it possible to set a RingCentral user's timezone through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681789/is-it-possible-to-set-a-ringcentral-users-timezone-through-the-api/51681794#51681794)